# Add edges using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Are there any easy method to add a large number of edges together in networkx

I want to add edges from a list.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "add a large number of edges together" you mean "add them to a graph", from `help(networkx.Graph)`:

```
 |  **Edges:**
 |  
 |  G can also be grown by adding edges.
 |  
 |  Add one edge,
 |  
 |  >>> G.add_edge(1, 2)
 |  
 |  a list of edges,
 |  
 |  >>> G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3)])
```

And so:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> g = nx.Graph()
>>> g.add_edges_from([(0,4),(1,2),(2,3)])
>>> g
<networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x1004b58d0>
>>> g.edges()
[(0, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

I would definitely recommend getting in the habit of reading the interactive documentation.  I was using `IPython`, and so all I had to do to quickly skim the available methods was make a graph `g`, and then type `g.[TAB]`.  This brought up a list, and `g.add_edges_from` was #3.

OTOH, if you simply want to add two lists of edges together, you can do that too:

```
>>> g0.edges() + g1.edges()
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> set(g0.edges() + g1.edges())
set([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (2, 3)])
```

Comment: Let me explain my predicament, I have a list like this 

list=
[[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
 [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5],
 [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5],
 [4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5],
 [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5]]

And if i want to create edges such as 1.1 - 1.2 - 1.3 ..
                                      2.1 - 2.2 - .. and so forth

What is the best way to go about it, using the existing list.

Comment: Please edit a smaller and complete example -- containing every single edge you want -- into your main question.  I can't tell from your example if you want 1.5 to have an edge to 2.1 or not.

Comment: i have posted the problem in this link.Thanks a lot for the help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143178/list-conversion

Answer (score 1):

Often graph data is stored in a file, which makes it easy to read with Pandas dataframe. For example, consider constructing a graph for a [seventh grader network](http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks/moreno_seventh). We can initialize our graph as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

#read the edge list
edges = pd.read_csv('./data/moreno_seventh/out.moreno_seventh_seventh', skiprows=2, sep = " ", header=None)
edges.columns = ['student1', 'student2', 'count']

#read node metadata
meta =pd.read_csv('./data/moreno_seventh/ent.moreno_seventh_seventh.student.gender', header=None)
meta.index += 1
meta.columns = ['gender']

#construct the graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
for row in edges.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(row[1]['student1'], row[1]['student2'], count=row[1]['count'])

#add meta data
for i in G.nodes():
    G.node[i]['gender'] = meta.ix[i]['gender']
```