# List conversion

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a way to convert a list like this

```
[[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
 [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5],
 [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5],
 [4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5],
 [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5]]
```

to something like this

```
[[(1.1,1.2),(1.2,1.3),(1.3,1.4),(1.4,1.5)],
 [(2.1,2.2),(2.2,2.3),(2.3,2.4),(2.4,2.5)]
 .........................................
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered this question. I know it's been downvoted, possibly because it doesn't meet the standard for a good question. I had just started out in python and thanks a lot for all you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to further comment from questioner, two answers:

```
# Original grid
grid = [[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
 [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5],
 [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5],
 [4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5],
 [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5]]


# Window function to return sequence of pairs.
def window(row):
    return [(row[i], row[i + 1]) for i in range(len(row) - 1)]
```

#### ORIGINAL QUESTION:

```
# Print sequences of pairs for grid
print [window(y) for y in grid]
```

#### UPDATED QUESTION:

```
# Take the nth item from every row to get that column.
def column(grid, columnNumber):
    return [row[columnNumber] for row in grid]


# Transpose grid to turn it into columns.
def transpose(grid):
    # Assume all rows are the same length.
    numColumns = len(grid[0])
    return [column(grid, columnI) for columnI in range(numColumns)]


# Return windowed pairs for transposed matrix.
print [window(y) for y in transpose(grid)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am just starting to learn python. Could you tell me what i should do if i had to print similarly column-wise [(1.1,2.1),(2.1),(3.1)..] etc

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been learning from a few tutorials, i haven't come across snippets like this. I guess they are a bit advanced for a Newbie like me. Any particular tutorials you could suggest.

Answer (score 12):

The following line should do it:

```
[list(zip(row, row[1:])) for row in m]
```

where `m` is your initial 2-dimensional list

**UPDATE for second question in comment**

You have to [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) (= exchange columns with rows) your 2-dimensional list. The python way to achieve a transposition of `m` is `zip(*m)`:

```
[list(zip(column, column[1:])) for column in zip(*m)]
```

Comment: Nothing like StackOverflow for getting the adrenaline pumping!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am just starting to learn python. Could you tell me what i should do if i had to print similarly column-wise
[(1.1,2.1),(2.1),(3.1)..] etc

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Learning programming via python :)

Comment: I prefer to write things long hand if the question is obviously a beginner,

Comment: @Joe I agree with you, but I always find it kind of magical to see and learn to sometimes write myself :) such condensed and expressive code. It reminds me that programming still is an art too. Furthermore I think it's good to grow up with some functional elements like `zip`.

Comment: Agreed. It's hard to find the right balance sometimes. Even in 'real' code I try to write things that only take 1 reading. But that's just personal style I suppose.

Comment: I can only agree to get familiar with functional concepts (`zip`, `map`, `lambda` etc.) nowadays, as soon as possible is important.

Comment: @halex : +1 for this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287736/is-it-possible-to-declare-arrays-in-one-java-file-and-use-them-in-a-different-ja/12287762#comment16482677_12287762)

Answer (score 1):

Another version would be to use `lambda` and `map`

```
map(lambda x: zip(x,x[1:]),m)
```

where `m` is your matrix of choice.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
[[(a[i],a[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(a)-1)] for a in A]
```