# Is it possible to declare arrays in one java file and use them in a different java file if they are all in the same package

Tags: java, arrays, class, variables

so how would you use that with a completely different java file but in the same package

```
public static void main (int[] args)
{
int [] HotDog = {18,8,10,0};
int [] ToastedChicken = {25,8,17,0};
int [] ToastedSteak = {30,8,22,0};
int [] ToastedEggT= {20,8,6,6};
int [] ToastedSteakE={36,8,22,6};
int [] ChickenRoll = {25,8,17,0};
int [] SteakRoll = {30,8,22,0};
int [] EggTomato = {20,8,6,6};
int [] CheeseTomato = {20,8,6,6};
int [] steakEgg = {36,8,22,6};`
```

IE here

```
if (contents ==  "Hot Dog")

{jLabel2.setText(HotDog[2]); }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to use where? Also, note that you are probably looking for `contents.equals("Hot Dog")` and not `==`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to make them static.  For example:

```
final class MyConstants {
    static final int[] HotDog = {18, 8, 10, 0};
    static final int[] ToastedChicken = {25, 8, 17, 0};
    static final int[] ToastedSteak = {30, 8, 22, 0};
    static final int[] ToastedEggT = {20, 8, 6, 6};
    static final int[] ToastedSteakE ={36, 8, 22, 6};
    static final int[] ChickenRoll = {25, 8, 17, 0};
    static final int[] SteakRoll = {30, 8, 22, 0};
    static final int[] EggTomato = {20, 8, 6, 6};
    static final int[] CheeseTomato = {20, 8, 6, 6};
    static final int[] SteakEgg = {36, 8, 22, 6};

    private MyConstants() {
        // Prevents users of this class from instantiating a useless instance of
        // this class, since all members are static.
    }
}
```

Then you can use them in any class in the same package like:

```
if (contents.equals("Hot Dog")) {
    jLabel2.setText(MyConstants.HotDog[2]);
}
```

Comment: Another important point is that they have been removed from the `main` method.

Comment: Note that though the package protected accessability is Ok in here - it is seldom the case.

Comment: For that matter, the `MyConstants` class can also have package access (unless it contains other things that are needed in other packages).

Comment: +1 I would create `interface MyConstants` instead of `class MyConstants`

Comment: @Nandkumar This would be Antipattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface

Answer (score 1):

And i will try to make those `Array` as `static` , so all the class trying to access these arrays gets the same array...

I could have also used `Singleton Principle with Composition` here...but thats overkill for this..

```
public class Test{
static int [] HotDog = {18,8,10,0};
static int [] ToastedChicken = {25,8,17,0};
static int [] ToastedSteak = {30,8,22,0};
static int [] ToastedEggT= {20,8,6,6};
static int [] ToastedSteakE={36,8,22,6};
static int [] ChickenRoll = {25,8,17,0};
static int [] SteakRoll = {30,8,22,0};
static int [] EggTomato = {20,8,6,6};
static int [] CheeseTomato = {20,8,6,6};
static int [] steakEgg = {36,8,22,6};

}

public class AccessIt{


Test.HotDog;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays are currently local to the method main. If you move them outside of the main method (exactly as they are) then they would be visible to other classes bin the same package as they would have package access. You will need to have a reference to that class (unless you make them static). In the example below I am calling the class X

```
int [] HotDog = {18,8,10,0};
int [] ToastedChicken = {25,8,17,0};
int [] ToastedSteak = {30,8,22,0};
int [] ToastedEggT= {20,8,6,6};
int [] ToastedSteakE={36,8,22,6};
int [] ChickenRoll = {25,8,17,0};
int [] SteakRoll = {30,8,22,0};
int [] EggTomato = {20,8,6,6};
int [] CheeseTomato = {20,8,6,6};
int [] steakEgg = {36,8,22,6};`

public static void main (int[] args)
{
     jLabel2.setText(new X().HotDog[2]); //will return 10
}
```

Also it is comon practice in java to name variables in camelCase. For example chickenRoll

Comment: Thank you for all the answers they were really helpful :) appreciate it

Comment: @user1649917 If you find answers useful then please upvote them and select one to be the solution to your question.